# Send Classification object cast as string object by system

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, ampscript

We are trying to create an Email Send Definition from a landing page. Ampscript is calling out to get a Send Classification object that will be a part of the Email Send Definition:

> SET @send_class_create = CreateObject("SendClassification")
>
> SetObjectProperty(*we set Send Classification properties here*)
>
> set @sendClass = InvokeCreate(@send_class_create,@statusMsg, @errorCode)

We now have a send classification object created. We will now use that object to define the Send Classification within the Email Send Definition object:

> SET @cr = CreateObject("EmailSendDefinition")
>
> SetObjectProperty(@cr, "Name","test")
>
> SetObjectProperty(@cr, "SendClassification",@sendClass)

SendClassification property requires a data type of SendClassification object according to the documentation.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/

If we try and run this code on a landing page the page returns an error:

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.SendClassification'.
>
> The function expression is invalid.  See inner exception for detail.
>
> Script: SetObjectProperty(@cr, "SendClassification", @sendClass)

The system seems to be casting the SendClassification object into a string object. I am specifically defining the object as the required type so I am not sure why the system is turning the object into a string object.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the sample code [on this page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_triggered_email_campaign_workflow/).  It's specific to a `TriggeredSendDefinition`, but it shows how to set the `SendClassification`:

```
tsd.SendClassification = new SendClassification();

//Available in the ET UI [Admin > Send Management > Send Classifications > Edit Item > External Key]
tsd.SendClassification.CustomerKey = "4201"; //required
```